# Where is windows icon stored in Win10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

It drives me nuts: Where is the plain windows icon stored in Windows 10?

winver.exe always used to be a safe bet, but it's not there any more.

I tried the usual candidates (explorer.exe, shell32.dll, ...)

Comment: There are tons of places for other native system icons>>>>>>>>https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons

Comment: What "Windows icon" are you interested in? Did you mean the blue windows icon in winver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is in the "%systemroot%\system32\mstsc.exe"  file

[image]

.
[Source of Information and more icon locations](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons)

Comment: I did actually look for myself and couldn't find it. So I learned something today. +1 from me. :)

Comment: Too many places to hide! Google knows where it is.....

Comment: indeed. too many places to hide.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Notice that this would only cover the light theme icon. There has to be another location with the dark theme icon (which is light colored to contrast with dark backgrounds), and it seems unlikely that they would be stored in different places. I suspect that this is an old Windows 8 icon (as suggested by the source linked in the answer).